# Xively API: can´t upload two variables

Tags: c++, arduino, xively

I´m having a few problems with the Xively API for Arduino. My project consists of sending data collected by analog sensors through the Ethernet Shield and print them it in the Xively website (in my account for now). The problem is, i´ve to send two different variables to xively: one for the LDR values (LDREsq) and the other for the temperature values that is being gathered with a DHT_11 temperature sensor. However, i can only send the LDR values, not the temeperature ones. I´ve built two void functions one for each variable and both are connect to xively using different API Keys. But i just can´t upload the temperature values.

Here is my code - only the two functions - sendData for the LDREsq and sendData2 for the DHT.temperature which is read earlier (if you don´t understand one thing just tell me, i´ll explain because part of the code may be in portuguese):

```
 `void sendData(int thisData) {
// if there's a successful connection:
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
  Serial.println("connecting...");
  // send the HTTP PUT request:
  client.print("PUT /v2/feeds/");
  client.print(FEEDID);
  client.println(".csv HTTP/1.1");
  client.println("Host: api.xively.com");
  client.print("X-ApiKey: ");//http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?PHPSESSID=tork80mn5auvtpqsblge27jvn1&topic=229543.0
  client.println(APIKEY);
  client.print("User-Agent: ");
  client.println(USERAGENT);
  client.print("Content-Length: ");

  // calculate the length of the sensor reading in bytes:
  // 8 bytes for "sensor1," + number of digits of the data:
 int thisLength = 8 + getLength(thisData);
  client.println(thisLength);

// last pieces of the HTTP PUT request:
  client.println("Content-Type: text/csv");
  client.println("Connection: close");
  client.println();

  // here's the actual content of the PUT request:
  client.print("LDREsq,");// the coma in the end is needed:
  client.println(thisData);

  Serial.println ("Success!");

} 
else {
  // if you couldn't make a connection:
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("connection failed");
  Serial.println("disconnecting.");
  Serial.println();
  client.stop();
}
 // note the time that the connection was made or attempted:
lastConnectionTime = millis();
}


// This method calculates the number of digits in the
// sensor reading.  Since each digit of the ASCII decimal
// representation is a byte, the number of digits equals
// the number of bytes:


void sendData2(int thisData2) {
    // if there's a successful connection:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connecting2...");
    // send the HTTP PUT request:
    client.print("PUT /v2/feeds/");
    client.print(FEEDID);
    client.println(".csv HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: api.xively.com");
    client.print("X-ApiKey: ");//http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?PHPSESSID=tork80mn5auvtpqsblge27jvn1&topic=229543.0
    client.println(APIKEY_2);
    client.print("User-Agent: ");
    client.println(USERAGENT);
    client.print("Content-Length: ");

    // calculate the length of the sensor reading in bytes:
    // 8 bytes for "sensor1," + number of digits of the data:
    int thisLength = 8 + getLength(thisData2);
    client.println(thisLength);

    // last pieces of the HTTP PUT request:
    client.println("Content-Type: text/csv");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();

    // here's the actual content of the PUT request:
    client.print("Temperatura,");
    client.println(thisData2);

    Serial.println ("Success 2!");

  } 
  else {
    // if you couldn't make a connection:
    Serial.println("connection failed 2");
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting 2.");
    client.stop();
  }
   // note the time that the connection was made or attempted:
  lastConnectionTime = millis();
}`
```

And this is where those are called

```
temp3++;
if(temp3 >= 20)
{
  sendData2(DHT.temperature);
  delay(100);
  temp3 = 0;
}


temp2++;
if (temp2 >= 10)
{
  sendData(estadoLDREsq);
  temp2 = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just let the Xivley library do the work for you:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <Xively.h>

// MAC address for your Ethernet shield
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

// Your Xively key to let you upload data
char xivelyKey[] = "[Put your Key here]";

// Define a datastream textual name 
char sensorId[] = "TEMP_001";

// Create as many datastreams you need (one in this case)
XivelyDatastream datastreams[] = {
  XivelyDatastream(sensorId, strlen(sensorId), DATASTREAM_FLOAT),
};

// Finally, wrap the datastreams into a feed
XivelyFeed feed([put your feed number here], datastreams, 1); // Where 1 is the number of datastreams we are wrapping

// Create a Etherent client
EthernetClient client;

// Let Xively know about the Ethernet client
XivelyClient xivelyclient(client);


// Run all the setup you need
void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (Ethernet.begin(mac) != 1){
    Serial.println("Error getting IP address via DHCP, trying again...");
    delay(15000);
  }
}


// Loop over
void loop(void) {

  // Read your sensor
  float celsius = [put your sensor reading value here];

  // Copy sensor reading to the apropriate datastream
  datastreams[0].setFloat(celsius);

  // Ask Xively lib to PUT all datastreams values at once
  int ret = xivelyclient.put(feed, xivelyKey);

  // Printout PUT result
  Serial.print("xivelyclient.put returned ");
  Serial.println(ret);

  // Wait 10 sec.
  delay(10000);  
}
```